Intuitive way how to apply modifier yet keep the original model
Oftentimes I end up wishing I could apply a modifier yet keep the original model. For example, I used a difference to create a hole in an object and now I want to edit the face in the hole, yet I want to keep the modifier in case I move the hole! See image, hole is highlighted in green.

I cannot edit the faces in the hole unless I apply the modifier. Is there a way to apply the modifier and keep the original object? I would be somewhat okay, if on change of the original object, the changed faces would reset, as it is ( I think? ) impossible to apply the same changes again to the new object. But of course, if the changes would stay too that would be great,
I am functionally looking for something like duplicating the object, saving a copy somewhere safe, and applying the modifier to the original. If I want, I would like to be able to revert the original object to it's saved state from the copy, before the modifier application.
Thanks!

No, you cannot edit procedural not "really" existing faces manually. You can change modified faces by other modifiers, since they all create procedural effects... for example first increase the resolution of an object with a Subdivision Surface modifier and then deform this highres mesh with a Displace modifier. But manual editing is not possible. You could only keep a duplicate with unapplied modifiers.

@GordonBrinkmann that seems to be a full answer.

This sounds like the XY Problem , what you want is not possible. There are however many different ways to build a model that would allow easy placement of the edited face according to some other object, if you tell us what your goal is, rather than your proposed solution.

It's a congregate of differently situations. Most recently, I needed to apply different materials on the new faces. But it's a problem I'm hitting regularly
